# Nvidia problems on Linux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

When I install blender through my package manager (xbps) or Flatpak, it does *not* detect my GPU. I should see the options for OptiX and CUDA (and maybe OpenCL, too?) for my GPU, but I just do not. When I run the binary in the tarball off of blender.org, I *do* see the CUDA option, but not OptiX. There's nothing wrong with my drivers as far as I can tell, `nvidia-smi` and the like work normally. I see no reason this shouldn't work that I know of. This was a problem with most distros (excluding Pop!_OS) that I ran. My solutions so far are to either wait for AMD to have good GPUs or just retreat back to Pop!_OS. Are there any common things to check for when nvidia drivers decide that working is too much effort?

#### Random Possibly Useless System Info:

RTX 2060 with proprietary drivers, 3900X, Void Linux

Comment: here on ubuntu I could only render using CUDA when running blender as root

Comment: @wilks wait what reason is there for running blender as root?

Comment: can't remember exactly but I think it was because of a bug in NVIDIA's drivers